# How should I best lock and refresh JPA entities?

Tags: jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I am relatively new to JPA and have become very confused about how to best optimistically lock and refresh entities. I would like a set of general purpose methods to handle this consistently in my project.

I may be calling the lock / refresh methods from within a method that does not know the state of the entity, it may have been passed a detatched or new / not saved entity object as well as one previously read from the database. For simplicity I would like my utility methods to handle all eventualities. Semantically the methods I am trying to implement are:

MyEntity refreshAndLock(MyEntity e)
Re-reads the entity from the database and locks it optimistically, or do nothing for entities yet to be saved to the database. Detached entities would also be re-read and locked and a managed version returned.

MyEntity refresh(MyEntity e)
Just re-read the entity, or do nothing for entities yet to be saved to the database. Detached entities would also be re-read.

MyEntity lockAndNotRefresh(MyEntity e)
Lock the version of the entity in memory (may already be out of date)

Any tips or links gratefully accepted. I haven't managed to find clear guidance on this which I'm surprised at since it seems like a common requirement.

Answer (score 1):

1st, my main recommendation is: Don't try to implement your own generic data access layer. You have the `EntityManager` at your hands doing all the stuff for you. Keep your code simple and don't overengeneer. With a generic layer you are very likely introduce new problems and lower maintainability.

2nd, you have to ask yourself, what will be the typical use case of your application in order to decide about locking. Locking always brings the problem of bottlenecks and possible dead locks. So if your application reads much more than it writes or is likely not to access the same entity at once, you're better off with optimistic locking and then treat exceptions. JPA provides you with versioning, so you always know if some other thread changed your object. If you really need pessimistic locking, then go ahead and set it for those cases.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am assuming optimistic locking using JPA versioning. What I'm not clear about what combination of the EntityManager interface calls can achieve the required result on an entity of an unknown state. It seems to me that in many cases you need to know the state of the entity being locked (new, persisted, detatched) which reduces the reusability of the code. My thought on the methods above is to centralise the code associated with these patterns, rather than repeating it over the code base. But of course there are pros and cons as you suggest.

Comment: Basically you only have two possibilities: Either the entity is managed by the EntityManager or not. In the 1st case, all changes you do on the entity are automatically synchronized with the underlying database at the end of the transaction. In the 2nd case, where you get that entity from some other point or created it via new, you can use merge() to make it managed. So, why do you feel, you have to care about the state of the entity? The EntityManager does it for you. In case of optimistic locking (yes, via @Version), you have to care about possible OptimisticLockExceptions.

Comment: And concerning your fear of having to repeat code over and over - as I stated above, there's practically no code for caring about the entity, all you have to do is to let the EntityManager know of it. You can then of course factor out some common use cases to not have them multiple times in your business logic. And you may care about exceptions at a central point. But again, in most cases you cannot or should not treat all entities the same, it may vary from use case to use case what to do with it and an exception.